# Action manhwa where the male lead goes back in time to the day the game-like world started

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I am looking for an action manhwa. ML goes back to the day the game-like world started. He wakes up near his friend who happens to be a girl and they are at universty and he knows what is gonna happen. He leads her and a few more people too.

Not sure if this is the same manhwa: There were god-like beings who support people as their player and ML doesnt accept one. There were monster-like things that live stream everything for the god-like beings.  I am not sure it is the same one but please help me if you know anything.

Comment: Do you remember any of the details of the world? You mention university; so does this take place in the modern world? It's action; how do people fight? With guns? Swords? Fists? Magic? What makes the world game-like? System pop ups? Experience points and skills?

Comment: @qazmlpok Yes modern world  game like part is there is safe spots and if remember correctly mc calls wukong to his friend and it gets the attention of monster but this is sadly all i remember

Comment: What do you mean by "wukong"? Is that his friend's name?

Comment: İt was another manhwa my bad all i rememeber about the one i am looking for is he returns and he is at universty next to his friend and he tries to understand what is going on and when he understands that is the day it all started he tries to take his friend and run but it is too late monsters are started kill people and if i remember right he even does a little count down by himself about the time  that they will come

Comment: @qazmlpok i think there was also a monster like thing that livestreams everything happening ?

Comment: @qazmlpok i found it thank you for trying to help me

Comment: That's great to hear - could you post it as an answer? That way anyone else interested can also get the title, and it will show as solved on the main page.

Answer (score 2):

It was [Return to Player](https://m.webtoons.com/en/action/return-to-player/list?title_no=2574&page=1).
Here is its summary:

> Ten years ago, a group of gods turned everyone on Earth into players of a sadistic game that forced them to kill monsters in real life -- or be killed themselves. Sehan Kim has already seen how this game will play out: everyone in the world dies except for him. When he's given the chance to go back in time and start a second playthrough, Sehan is determined to change the course of events and beat the gods at their own game.

Comment: Please make sure you come back to this question and accept the answer when that action is available to you (in a couple of days).